# Send data with segue from MainViewController to SideMenu

Tags: swift, xcode

I am using a [SideMenu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu) to show my application menu. The problem is that I didn't find a way to pass data from my `MainViewController` to the `TableViewController` because from the `MainViewController` the `segue.destination` is `SideMenu.UISideMenuNavigationController`.

This is a screen with the views and maybe you understand better:

[image]

So my data needs to arrive from the first to the third view.

Would be great if an example with delegates also can be provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to do that. For example you can use delegates to pass data between view controllers, or use notification center.
As i understand from your question you would like to use segues. For that approach the solution is the following:

In "Satari" view controller (I mean third view controller, let say SatariViewController) define some variable:

```
var test : String?
```

In the first view controller add the following code

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "segueName" {
                let navViewController = segue.destination as! UISideMenuNavigationController
                let satariVC = navViewController.viewControllers.first as! SatariViewController
                satariVC. test = "Data from first view controller"
    }
}
```

So by this code you can pass data from first controller to third controller. However I think more solid solution would be the use of delegates.

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you please provide an example with delegates please?

Comment: Please take look at https://www.codebeaulieu.com/36/Passing-data-with-the-protocol-delegate-pattern

Answer (score 2):

Hi I've just run into the same problem. I managed to use what Vah.Sah suggested with the present function that the SideMenu github docs suggest.

In the ViewController for your side menu:

```
var test: String?
```

In the first ViewController:

```
@IBAction func menuPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let menuVC = SideMenuManager.default.menuLeftNavigationController?.viewControllers.first as! YourSideMenuVC

    menuVC.test = "test"
    present(SideMenuManager.default.menuLeftNavigationController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And because the viewDidLoad function is called immediately with SideMenu, you can access the variable through viewDidAppear.

Also, I've done the same to access functions from the firstViewController with delegates.

SideMenu ViewController:

```
protocol FirstViewControllerProtocol: class {
    func doSomething()
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate:FirstViewControllerProtocol!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func goBack(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.doSomething()
    }
}
```

In first ViewController:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, FirstViewControllerProtocol {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func menuPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        let menuVC = SideMenuManager.default.menuLeftNavigationController?.viewControllers.first as! YourSideMenuVC

        menuVC.delegate = self
        present(SideMenuManager.default.menuLeftNavigationController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // Define doSomething()
    func doSomething() {

    }
}
```

Comment: You saved my Day!! Works like a Charm :)